# Is there a way to return express instances in TypeScript classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to create the express server for my project in an external module. Everything works fine until I try to do something with the `app` object in my main file.

server.ts:

```js
import express from "express";
import OutputLevel from "../types/OutputLevels";

class Server {
    /**
     * Creates an express web server
     * @param {Number} port The port the server is listening on
     * @param {OutputLevel} [outputLevel] The level of console output (commonly based on CLI arguments) {@link OutputLevel}
     * @returns {Express}
     */
    constructor(port: Number, outputLevel?: OutputLevel) {
        const app = express();
        app.listen(port, () => {
            if (outputLevel && outputLevel >= 2) console.log(`[Server @ ${port}] Listening @ http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
        return app;
    }
}

export default Server;
```

index.ts:

```js
import Server from "./server/server";
import OutputLevel from "./types/OutputLevels";

let app = new Server(2020, OutputLevel.INFO);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello world")
});
```

The `get` part gets marked as an error by intellisense with the note `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Server'.`. Maybe this has something to do with me using classes and constructors instead of functions, but I'm trying to use a class here.

Comment: That's a weird way to use a class-- a constructor shouldn't return a value.  That's more like a factory pattern.  If you are encapsulating `app` inside of the `Server` class you either need to proxy calls to the underlying `app` or question why you are wrapping the app in a Server class just to call methods directly on the Express app object.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into classes a little more, thanks for the advice!